# Wordpress site reloading shows 2 headers

Tags: wordpress

There are two header bars, one for mobile, one for desktop. On refresh both are visible. Is there any way to only visible the current header when the site reloads.

Comment: is the header bar created by yourself ? or is it included as a theme / plugin of wordpress?

Comment: I think there are two added into code you need to hide it using CSS, sometime  JS is used to hide show the elements, but they show while page is in loading state.